# Мне нужно отобрать не повторенные сообщения из почты. Какие существуют способы? Аналитика почты

Tags: python, email

У нас есть множество писем от разных отправителей  нужно отобрать тех отправителей которые писали только один раз. Еще нужно сделать это в рамках текущего года по сегодняшний день.

Я даже не понимаю через что лучше работать с почтой. Есть ли какие то api, парсить через selenium очень костыльно. или все таки придётся через библиотеку для работы с почтой в python.

На английском Стэковере мой вопрос за минусовали и закрыли как я понял не за конкретный вопрос. но подскажите хотя бы где примерно искать информацию если возможно или на каких форумах нормально задовать такие вопросы. наверника у кого то есть опыт в этом.

Спасибо. (Заранее спасибо за минусы..)

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть почта на почтовом сервере, вы можете использовать стандартные модули imaplib для доступа к ним, а затем у вас есть почта для получения некоторых элементов из почты - например, адреса электронной почты - и вы можете использовать collections.Counter, чтобы подсчитать, сколько раз оно было использовано. Вместо стандартного **imaplib** вы можете использовать **ImapClient, imbox, imap-tools** или другие модули, которые могут быть проще в использовании. Я думаю, что использовать selenium будет слишком сложно и он будет работать намного медленнее. Вот один из подходов:

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

mailbox = MailBox('imap.yandex.ru')
mailbox.login('mail', 'password')

print(mailbox.folder.list())

mailbox.folder.set('needed_folder')
mails = [[msg.from_, str(msg.date), msg.text] for msg in mailbox.fetch()]
```